# How to determine the version of Git Credential Manager for Windows?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

Is there a command or other way to determine the version of Credential Manager in my git installation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `Git-Credential-Manager`'s GitHub [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/CredentialManager.md)

> Assuming the GCM has been installed, using your favorite Windows console (Command Prompt, PowerShell, ConEmu, etc.), use the following command to interact directly with the GCM.

```
    git credential-manager [<command> [<args>]]
```

So to display the current version you can use

```
    git credential-manager version
```

If you are using a newer git for Windows version that includes credential-manager-core the command is:

```
git credential-manager-core --version
```

Comment: @Ray Megal, I think that the "correct" name regardless if it's Windows or not, is "credential-manager" ( https://aka.ms/gcm/rename ). If you go to the directory for that executable (C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin for git >=2.36.1), you can see there's two executables for "git-credential-manager", one with the "-core.exe" and the other without. If you see the properties of both, you can see they are the same, and on the details for the one with the "-core.exe", you can see that the original filename is "git-credential-manager.exe".

Answer (score 1):

Run `git credential-manager version` as described [here](http://microsoft.github.io/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/Docs/CredentialManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

With more recent installs of git, try either of the following:

```
git-credential-manager --version
git credential-manager --version
```